# Visualizing waveform for stored (not real-time) audio using Web Audio API

Tags: audio, visualization, web-audio-api, mediarecorder-api

I'm using MediaRecorder API to record a media stream from a microphone. And I want to draw a visualization of the recorded audio on a canvas. Web Audio API's AnalyserNode visualises real-time audio from the stream.

Is there a way to visualize a waveform of a static/stored (as opposed to real-time) audio using Web Audio API's AnalyserNode?